# Fill field name in case of file_field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested_form and this form on it :

```
  <%= f.fields_for :uploads do |file| %>
      <%= file.label 'File name :'%>
      <%= file.text_field :name, :size => "19", :id=>"field" %>    
      <%= file.file_field :file if file.object.new_record? %> 
      <p>
      <%= file.link_to_remove "Delete" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.link_to_add "Add", :uploads, :class=>"btn" %>
```

I would like to have the text_field "name" filled when the user choose a file (just the name and extention) but I don't know how to do that with javascript as I can have a lot of file_fields and not only one.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Do you plan to choose a correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :uploads do |file| %>
    <%= file.label 'File name :'%>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, :size => 19 %>    
    <%= file.file_field :file if file.object.new_record? %> 
    <%= file.link_to_remove "Delete" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.link_to_add "Add", :uploads, :class=>"btn" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with JS the approach I came up with basically sets a data attribute on your input with the value you want populated.

When your view renders it will have data attributes embedded in the inputs you want, then after the document is ready you can use jQuery to select all inputs with that particular data attribute and set their values.

In your view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :uploads do |file| %>
    <%= file.label 'File name :'%>
    <%= file.text_field :name, :size => "19", :id=>"field", :data => { "for-auto-fill" => "some value" } %>    
    <%= file.file_field :file if file.object.new_record? %> 
    <p>
    <%= file.link_to_remove "Delete" %>
<% end %>

<%= f.link_to_add "Add", :uploads, :class=>"btn" %>
```

In your javascript:

```
/* Select all elements with a 'for-auto-fill' data attribute */
$('[for-auto-fill]').each(function(){
  /* For each one, set it's value to the value that you set on the data attribute */
  $(this).val(($(this).data().forAutoFill));
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry the JS isn't highlighting comments correctly. I'm not really sure how to get around it, but i thought inline comments would be clearer.